# How to create a Java DB on embedded mode

Tags: java, derby

I downloaded an apche derby Database and would like to connect to my java application on embedded mode and not server mode.

1. How do I create a new database?
2. How do I connect to it from my application using NetBeans IDE?

Comment: *How do I connect to it from my application using NetBeans IDE* -- Are you going to control your application using NetBeans?

Answer (score 1):

http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/getstart/index.html is your friend. Learn how to run ij, go through the tutorials, it's a good document and will step you through all the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Append `;create=true` to your JDBC url, and Derby will create the database if it does not yet exist.